# unexpected type, expecting name

Tags: mysql, go

i have try to use golang. iam new for this golang. when i try to connect to mysql i got some error like this :

./testCOnnection.go:9:35: syntax error: unexpected type, expecting name
./testCOnnection.go:15:1: syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body
./testCOnnection.go:36:5: syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body

i have run using root.

here my source code

package main

```
import "database/sql"
import "fmt"
import _"github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"

type trade_history struct {
    id, final_meta_report_id, trading_account_id, lp, lp2, lp3             int
    symbol, price, price_type, time, type, status, created_at, updated_at  string
    qty, pegged_distance, price_limit                      double
}
var db *sql.DB
var err error

funct getTradingHistory (final_Meta_report_ID int) (err error){
    username := "lalala"
    password := "felixsiong"
    host := "trades.xawrs2.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com"
    port := 3306
    db := "trading_dashboard"

    //use Sprintf if you wanna parse a string with values
    conn := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@%s:%s/%s", username, password, host, port, db)
    db, err = sql.Open("mysql", conn)
    defer db.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    var p trade_history

    //if you have multiple lines of texts use ` instead of "
    err = db.QueryRow(`select id, final_meta_report_id, 
    trading_account_id, symbol, qty, price, price_type, time, lp, 
    lp2, lp3, pegged_distance, price_limit, time_limit, type, status, created_at`).Scan(&p)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }


    fmt.Printf("id: %d\n Final_meta_report_id: %d\n trading_account_id: %d\n symbol: %s\n qty: %.2f\n price: %s\n price_type: %s\n time: %s\n lp: %d\n lp2: %d\n lp3: %d\n pegged_distance: %.2f\n")

    return err
}

func main() {
    getTradingHistory(2074)
}
```

i have update my code become this

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

var db *sql.DB
var err error

type trade_history struct {
    id, final_meta_report_id, trading_account_id, lp, lp2, lp3             int
    symbol, price, price_type, time, types, status, created_at, updated_at string
    qty, pegged_distance, price_limit                                      float64
}

func getTradingHistory(final_Meta_report_ID int) error {
    username := "lalala"
        password := "felixsiong"
        host := "trades.xawrs2.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com"
        port := 3306
        db := "trading_dashboard"

    //use Sprintf if you wanna parse a string with values
    conn := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:%d)/%s", username, password, host, port, db)
    //conn := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@%s:%s/%s", username, password, host, port, db)
    db, err = sql.Open("mysql", conn)
    defer db.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    var p trade_history

    //if you have multiple lines of texts use ` instead of "
    err := db.QueryRow("select id, final_meta_report_id, 
    trading_account_id, symbol, qty, price, price_type, time, lp, 
    lp2, lp3, pegged_distance, price_limit, time_limit, type, status, created_at From trade_history Where final_Meta_report_ID = ?", final_Meta_report_ID ).Scan(&p)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }

    fmt.Printf("id: %d\n Final_meta_report_id: %d\n trading_account_id: %d\n symbol: %s\n qty: %.2f\n price: %s\n price_type: %s\n time: %s\n lp: %d\n lp2: %d\n lp3: %d\n pegged_distance: %.2f\n")

    return err
}

func main() {
    getTradingHistory(2074)
}
```

but i still got error like this if i run using terminal

```
./testCOnnection.go:41:55: newline in string
./testCOnnection.go:41:55: syntax error: unexpected newline, expecting comma or )
./testCOnnection.go:43:57: syntax error: unexpected type at end of statement
./testCOnnec
```

tion.go:43:109: invalid character U+003F '?'
./testCOnnection.go:43:144: newline in string

and if i run using visual studio code i got error like this

myConnectionMySql.go:5:8: cannot find package "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql" in any of:
/usr/local/go/src/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql (from $GOROOT)
/Users/fuad/go/src/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql (from $GOPATH)
exit status 1

Process exiting with code: 1my question is how to fix my problem here ?

Comment: Installing an IDE like Jetbrains Goland or VSCode with Go Plugin will help you write valid Go code. The errors in the code above would have been highlighted even before running the code.

Comment: You have a lot of code here, and presumably the error occurs on one or two lines. It's expected that a good question on stackoverflow reduces the code down to a minimal form that still reproduces the error. Presumably that's code around line 41 where there's a newline in your string.

Comment: ok i will check first one by one

Answer (score 2):

I have rewritten your code:

```sh
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

var myDB *sql.DB
var err error

type trade_history struct {
    id, final_meta_report_id, trading_account_id, lp, lp2, lp3             int
    symbol, price, price_type, time, types, status, created_at, updated_at string
    qty, pegged_distance, price_limit                                      float64
}

func getTradingHistory(final_Meta_report_ID int) error {
    username := "lalala"
    password := "felixsiong"
    host := "trades.xawrs2.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com"
    port := 3306
    db := "trading_dashboard"

    //use Sprintf if you wanna parse a string with values
    conn := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:%d)/%s", username, password, host, port, db)
    myDB, err = sql.Open("mysql", conn)
    defer myDB.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    err = myDB.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }

    var p trade_history

    //if you have multiple lines of texts use ` instead of "
    err = myDB.QueryRow(`select id, final_meta_report_id,
    trading_account_id, symbol, qty, price, price_type, time, lp,
    lp2, lp3, pegged_distance, price_limit, time_limit, type, status, created_at`).Scan(&p)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }

    fmt.Println("id: %d\n Final_meta_report_id: %d\n trading_account_id: %d\n symbol: %s\n qty: %.2f\n price: %s\n price_type: %s\n time: %s\n lp: %d\n lp2: %d\n lp3: %d\n pegged_distance: %.2f\n")

    return err
}

func main() {
    if getTradingHistory(2074) != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
}
```

There is a lots of problem:

- `type` is keyword for `go`
- `funct` must be `func`
- `myDB.QueryRow(....).Scan(&p)` need to rewrite it. you can find proper example form [here](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/blob/84241ad3f47266ef3ee7cdbc13975c48ce66fa83/driver_test.go#L525)
- `fmt.Println("id: %d\n Final_meta_report_id:.......` need to rewrite it in right way for `go`
- `double` will be replaced by `float32/float64`

Comment: Uddin Al Azad i have update my source code but i still got error in here

Answer (score 1):

The error `syntax error: unexpected type, expecting name` is about the usage of reserved keyword `type` as variable name at specified line number. Keyword `type` is there to create new types in golang, cannot use it as variable name.

And there is type while declaring the function. It supposed to be `func` not `funct`. Remaining two errors are about this.

Comment: i still got error when i try to change my source code any idea here ?

Comment: What is the error you are facing now? is the question updated with latest error? I would suggest you to use VSCode with Go plugin which will be very helpful to notice errors before compilation

Comment: yes i have use VScode with GoPlugin but there is notice error if i run use go only got error like this myConnectionMySql.go:5:8: cannot find package "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql" in any of:
 /usr/local/go/src/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql (from $GOROOT)
 /Users/fuad/go/src/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql (from $GOPATH)
exit status 1
Process exiting with code: 1 if i run using terminal i got another error

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
funct getTradingHistory (final_Meta_report_ID int) (err error){}
```

to:

```
func getTradingHistory (final_Meta_report_ID int) (err error){}
```

Comment: i still got error here after i change my source code any idea for fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
funct getTradingHistory
```

Should be changed as

```
func getTradingHistory
```

Comment: i have update my source code but i still got error how to fix it ?